# SparseArray Input

Tags: matrix, sparse-arrays

How to create a SparseArray without using lists of rule in MMA?

In MMA we can define a SparseArray using lists of rule

```
s = SparseArray[{{1, 1} -> 1, {2, 2} -> 2, {3, 3} -> 3, {1, 3} -> 4}]
```

Is it possible that we can create SparseArray using vectors input?

E.g.:

```
u1 = {1, 2, 3, 1};    
v1 = {1, 2, 3, 3};    
w1 = {1, 2, 3, 4};

s = SparseArray[u1,v1,w1,...]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`SparseArray` also supports

```
SparseArray[positions -> values]
```

So on the example:

```
SparseArray[Transpose@{u1, v1} -> w1]
```

Answer (score 7):

A one liner

```
s = Rule @@@ Transpose@{Transpose@{u1, v1}, w1} // SparseArray
```

Check

```
s // MatrixForm
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 1 & 0 & 4 \\
 0 & 2 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 3 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Nice! thanks a lot!

Comment: Also `(s = SparseArray[{#[[1]], #[[2]]} -> #[[3]] &  /@ Transpose[{u1, v1, w1}]]) // MatrixForm`